# how to check activation of email before sending it in Postmark

Tags: postmark

I create a project using Golang. and I have function to send emails that use Postmark . But I got this error "422 You tried to send to recipient(s) that have been marked as inactive. Found inactive addresses: .... . Inactive recipients are ones that have generated a hard bounce, a spam complaint, or a manual suppression.".

How can i check if the address is active or not, before try to send it ? . There is no mention of that on postmark documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use Postmark's [Suppression dump](https://postmarkapp.com/developer/api/suppressions-api#suppression-dump) API.

```
/message-streams/{stream_id}/suppressions/dump
```

> It doesn't give you the option to check one email at a time, but you
> can get the entire suppression list downloaded locally and check for
> inactive recipients offline.

Here's an example response from Postmark:

```json
{  
  "Suppressions":[
    {  
      "EmailAddress":"address@wildbit.com",
      "SuppressionReason":"ManualSuppression",
      "Origin": "Recipient",
      "CreatedAt":"2019-12-17T08:58:33-05:00"
    },
    {  
      "EmailAddress":"bounce.address@wildbit.com",
      "SuppressionReason":"HardBounce",
      "Origin": "Recipient",
      "CreatedAt":"2019-12-17T08:58:33-05:00"
    },
    {  
      "EmailAddress":"spam.complaint.address@wildbit.com",
      "SuppressionReason":"SpamComplaint",
      "Origin": "Recipient",
      "CreatedAt":"2019-12-17T08:58:33-05:00"
    }
  ]
}
```